# What is the difference between phy_position_x and x in GameMaker: Studio?

Tags: game-maker

This is not covered anywhere in the documentation that I can find.

I am using the physics engine, and the reported phy_position_x and x values are different, such that (phy_position_x, phy_position_y) is (0, 0) and (x, y) is (origin x, origin y).

Why are they different and is one preferred over the other in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `phy_position_x` and `phy_position_y` are in the top-left of the object fixture.

`x` and `y` are at the sprite origin.

The `phy_com_x` and `phy_com_y` are at the center point of the fixture. These are usually the same as the sprite origin.   In the documentation, linked [here](https://manual.gamemaker.io/monthly/en/GameMaker_Language/GML_Reference/Physics/physics_mass_properties.htm), there is a way to modify this, but initially it is the center of the collision shape from the Physics panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the documentation for all three:

[x](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/movement/x.html)

> **Returns**: Real
>
> **Description**: The x value of an instance is the horizontal position in
>   the current room, measured in pixels. This value can be either 0,
>   positive or minus, where 0 is the left hand side of the room and
>   moving right increases x, moving left decreases x (a negative value
>   for x means that the instance has gone outside the left side of the
>   room). You can even give x a real value like 12.345, but as you cannot
>   get .345 of a pixel, the instance may not appear to have moved,
>   although these values will be maintained and used internally by
>   GameMaker: Studio and are perfectly valid.
>
> By setting the x (and y) values you can make the object jump around
>   the room to the position of your choice, or you can add and subtract
>   to them by smaller amounts to give the illusion of movement without
>   actually using the built in speed and direction functions. This should
>   be taken into account when making your games as often one type of
>   movement lends itself to a particular style of game-play more than
>   another.

[phy_position_x](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/physics/physics%20variables/phy_position_x.html)

> **Returns**: Real
>
> **Description**: This variable can be used to get (or to set) the x
>   position of the instance within the game room physics world. Please
>   note that the physics world may present errors when instances are
>   moved by directly setting this variable as it will interrupt the
>   continuous simulation.

[phy_com_x](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/physics/physics%20variables/phy_com_x.html)

> **Returns**: Real
>
> **Description**: This read-only variable will return the x position of the
>   instances center of mass. This is calculated automatically based on
>   the density, inertia and mass of the instance as defined by the
>   appropriate functions.

As the name implies, the `phy_position_x` is the position of the physics object that's representing the object. It's different from the `phy_com_x` because the `phy_com_x` is at the center of the mass of the physics object, most likely at the center of the object.

Comment: Thanks for this; I am familiar with those definitions. I'm looking for the practical difference between x and phy_position_x on a physics-enabled object. Can you improve upon or make a clearer explanation than the answer I made on this question? That would drive at the heart of my confusion.

Comment: The practical difference is they're used for different things. Most things will be defined by their center or top left. You'll find both varieties here.

Answer (score 0):

phy_position_x and phy_position_y are the position variables for use on a physics enabled world.
x and y variables are the position of an object in a world (room) without physics.

That's the diference of them.